# how to run two sql commands in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, database

there are two tables 1. employees and 2. departments

when I try to describe the two tables with the following code

```
desc employees;
desc departments;
```

I am getting the following error

Object to be described could not be found.

Comment: **`desc`** is not an sql command, it is a sql*plus command.

Comment: How are you executing those commands? What client are you using? What is the **exact** error message?

Comment: @danihp when I use it individually, like desc employees - it is describing the table. Why it is not running for desc employees; desc departments

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I am using Oracle 10g database express edition

Comment: I say that [describe](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm#i2697562) is not an SQL Standard Command neither a Oracle SQL Command it is a SQL*PLUS tool command. This is not a solution, only a remark. In question title you talk about sql commands but samples are not. See @APC answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can never run two `sqlplus` commands at a time, you can queue your commands in your `script`, and execute the script. 
working principle is like this, when it sees the first word , if it realises as a proper keyword, it blindly try to execute what ever next to it.!

Answer (score 1):

`DESCRIBE` is [a SQL*Plus command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref257).  We can only run it in a SQL*Plus client, or an emulator such as PL/SQL Developer's command window.

In SQL*Plus we get this error message when we attempt to describe an object which doesn't exist:

```
SQL> desc t34
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object t34 does not exist


SQL>
```

Whereas in SQL Developer worksheets we get this

```
desc t34
ERROR:                           
-------------------------------- 
ERROR: object T34 does not exist
```

So you must be using a different client.

In the end it does not matter, all the messages mean the same thing: the object doesn't exist.  The most likely explanation is that you're connected as a user different from the owner of the tables.

Comment: I am using oracle 10g database express edition. it's it an SQL plus client ??